# VWP - Entering USA from Canada after 90 days in Canada

Tags: canada, us-visa-waiver-program

I am trawling the internet for an answer to my question and thought this forum could help.

I am an Australian citizen and have been holidaying in Canada for more than 90 days. I would now like to enter the USA for a 5 day holiday before returning to Canada for 1 day and flying back to Australia.

Is this possible under the Visa Waiver Program and ESTA, or do I require a B2 visa?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you transit in the US at all on your way to Canada from Australia (or wheverever you started from)?

Comment: @GregHewgill - No I did not transit through the US at all. I flew direct from Australia to Canada and have spent the last 96 days only in Canada

Comment: Is there a specific reason you think there could be a problem with entering the US under the VWP in these conditions? I don’t see one. Don’t forget you need an ESTA whether you enter by air or land now.

Comment: @jcaron I can't find anything definitive online, but a ski forum I participate in is adamant I would need a b2 visa. From what I've comprehended online (USA gov websites etc) I should be fine.

I'm afraid of the consequences of misunderstanding anything and being "denied entry" being a red mark against my name and any future ESTA or B2 applications in the years to come.

Comment: Why does the ski forum imagine you would need a visa?  They're wrong, though this is a very commonly misunderstood aspect of the VWP.

Comment: @phoog their reasoning is that because Canada has a common border with USA that my 90 days started to elapse when I entered Canada directly from Australia

Comment: @techbinding001 Nope, Canada and the US are not a single immigration area (like Schengen for instance), so entering Canada does not start the VWP 90-day clock. There is a US rule to avoid visa runs (hopping across the border to reset the clock) when you were in the US **first** and made a **short** trip to Canada (or Mexico, or nearby islands), but not if you never entered the US (or not recently at least).

Answer (score 6):

You have not yet entered the United States on this trip. As an Australian, you are eligible to apply for entry under the [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html) by obtaining an ESTA.

There is a rule regarding entering the US on the VWP and taking short trips to nearby countries, but since you have not yet entered the US that rule does not apply to you. From the above linked page:

> If you are admitted to the United States under the VWP, you may take a short trip to Canada, Mexico, or a nearby island and generally be readmitted to the United States under the VWP for the remainder of the original 90 days granted upon your initial arrival in the United States.